# Reason: Any way to batch convert WAV to REX?

Tags: daw, wav, batch

I've used several DAWs over the years, and my sample library has grown to a considerable size. I've been playing with Reason lately, and I rather like it, but one big turnoff is that 99% of my drumloops are WAV. Is there any way to batch-convert WAV loops to REX?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. The trouble is the hit detection for the conversion is sort of hit and miss. And most tools, to even get semi-accurate hit detection happening, require you give it the BPM (as opposed to auto-detecting the BPM) before extracting hits.

There's a separate product available from Propellerhead for the creation of REX files called [ReCycle](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/recycle/) that you might want to check out. I'm not sure if it has any batch processing facilities. It didn't the last time I used it, but that was many years ago.

You might also want to have a look at [Translator from Chicken Systems](http://chickensys.com/products/sw_iteminfo.php?sw_name=Translator+Pro). It's a more generic sample filer converter but it does support REX output. It's batch facilities are better, but again, going from WAV -> REX might not work. If you were moving from another sample format to REX it might be able to do batch conversion because the other sample format might have the hits and BPM embedded in the format as meta data already.

Comment: Last I checked, ReCycle has no batch processing. Translator looks promising - I'll snag the demo and give it a shot. I'll let you know what I come up with. It's a pity that ReCycle can't be automated. (Is there a way of automating tasks like that in Windows?) EDIT: Maybe batch-processing in ReCycle could be jury-rigged with something like this? http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: What's frustrating is that there could be a product (lol, for example Recycle) that could auto convert other slice formatted files (ACID, apple Loops, etc) because those have the tempo, number of beats, and slice markers already in them.

Answer (score 1):

I used Reaper v4.261 To successfully convert a number of .rx2 files to .wav files

A trial version can be downloaded from http://www.reaper.fm/

Once installed, Go to:

File
Batch File/Item converter

[Short cut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>]

A window will pop up - You need to add the files you want to convert into that window by clicking on the "Add" button and clicking "Add Files". Highlight the ones you want...

e.g. `C:\Cakewalk Content\Audio Library\Loops\Loopmasters\BREAKS DRUM N BASS\DANNY BYRD\REXFILE1.rx2` , `REXFILE2.rx2` etc.

If you want to save the file with the same name, leave the box ticked that says "Use source file directory". You can also leave the Output format as "WAV" and the "Resample mode (if needed)" as Better.

Enter Filename as: "`$source`" (Other wildcards can be used but this is easiest).

Click "Convert all"

When done, go to your directory where the original rx2 files were kept and open it. Your new .WAV files should be in there. Go ahead and open them up in a wav editor such as Goldwave or a Digital Audio Workstation such as Reason.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was about going the opposite direction, which Reaper doesn't support.

Answer (score -1):

The older PC version of recycle, I just drag / drop 40 files into the recycle window. It'll open up 40 windows… and do “save all” and just keep hitting “return” … *BUT* be mindful of the folder you use… as it'll pick the last one… reason studios really do need to update it.. rx2 is a great format, saves space BUT need to be improved to be better. E.g., better slice detection and of course batch mode, and perhaps even an editor.